# What is the most user friendly program to record video from webcam in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, software-rec, video-capture

I would like to use my web camera to record video.

What are the some easy and user friendly programs one can use for this purpose in Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ManyCam](http://www.manycam.com/) and [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) can record from a webcam, although ManyCam is a bit easier than VLC. I think [Windows Live Movie Maker](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-movie-maker?os=other) can capture from a webcam, although I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Manycam sucks, it won't record audio unless you pay money. VLC is not user friendly and is a pain in the ass. I would suggest Windows Movie Maker.